# Is there a canonical location for systemd environment files?

Tags: systemd

Is there a canonical location for systemd `EnvironmentFile`s?

I've seen

- `/opt/apps/someapp.env`, app install directories
- `/etc/conf.d/someapp.env`, semi-official-looking-but-hard-to-google directory
- `/etc/system.d/someapp.env`, next to unit files

Where would you expect to see them in a well organized system?

Comment: On Debian based systems I believe `/etc/default` is commonly used. Not sure if `canonical` though.

Comment: [Red Hat systems](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-managing_services_with_systemd-unit_files) place them in `/etc/sysconfig`.